# Ember this.get() is not retrieving property on component

Tags: ember.js

Storing a Plain JS NodeList in an Ember component property, but when trying to access it in a function using either this.prop or this.get('prop') or get(this, 'prop') it only returns undefined.

I have console.log(this.prop) and I get the NodeList. Just retrieving it from within a function which is within the didRender() hook will not return the NodeList.

I must be missing something obvious, like I need to make this into an Ember Object first?

My steps:
1. In Ember component `didRender()` hook
2. Use plain JS using `querySelectorAll('.my-class')` -> returns a NodeList `// working!`
3. Add event listeners to Nodelist  `// working!`
4. Set component property to NodeList value `this.set('prop', Nodelist)` `// working!`
5. Call event listener function outside `didRender()` hook  `// working!`
6. In function (outside `didRender()` hook), attempt to retrieve variable using `this.prop`, or `this.get('prop')` or `get(this, 'prop')` and assign to variable. `// NOT working!`

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { get, set } from '@ember/object';
export default Component.extend({
    myProp: null,
    handlerForButtons(e){ // Fires when any button clicked. Handler for buttons.
        e.preventDefault();

        let currentButton = e.target;
        currentButton.style.display = 'none';
        let currentSibling = currentButton.nextElementSibling;
        currentSibling.style.display = 'block';

        // this assignment myProp is undefined
        let myProp = this.myProp; // also this.get('myProp'); or get(this, 'myProp'); not working.
        console.log("myProp: ", myProp);
    },

    didRender(){

        let allButtons =  document.querySelectorAll('ul.aog-list li > button');
        this.addListeners(allButtons, ['click', 'keydown'], this.handlerForButtons);


        let allSiblings =   document.querySelectorAll('ul.aog-list .aog-wrap');
        this.set('myProp', allSiblings);
        console.log("SET myProp: ", this.myProp); // Shows a NodeList of 32 items

        allSiblings.forEach(function(e){
            e.style.display = 'none'; //Hide sibling divs for initial state
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: please show your code! probably your loose the `this`-context somewhere.

Comment: can you add your template?
how the action is being called _could_ change the `this` as well

Comment: clearly the problem is how you are calling handlerForButtons

Comment: Thanks folks. I'm going to try this in a more declarative way (more Ember Way-ish) and see if that makes things simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'd personally rewrite this, you need to access the actual element of the component to add the listeners: `this.element.addEventListener` rather than `this.addEventListener`

But you really should rewrite this to be more ember-y, and use actions to handle the click events, because then you avoid all of these problems.

Comment: Thanks @Donald. The listeners seems to be adding fine, as they work, but yes, I'm rethinking the whole thing using a declarative (ember-y) approach. Thanks for the input!